# Splitting a string of numbers into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I keep getting an error in the console that *.split* is not a function. Here is my code:

```
function addEnds(list) {

        var array = new Array();
        array = list.split(',');

        console.log(array);
    }
```

Basically, I want the list to equal a series of number separated by a comma, example: `1,2,3,4,5,` and am trying to put those into an array.  I've researched about using *.split* but for some reason, I'm just not getting it.

Comment: can you show how you are calling your function.  `split` is a **string** method, are you calling your function like addEnds("1,2,3,4,5") ?

Comment: It’s a problem with what you’re passing as `list`, but you haven’t shown that. Also, you don’t need to initialize the array like that. `split()` will make a new array.

Comment: for now just in the console i'm typing addEnds(2,3,5,8,0); or any other random series of numbers.

Comment: well, that's not a string ... you could try `function addEnds(...list) { return list; }` - or `function addEnds() { return Array.from(arguments));` or even `function addEnds() { return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);}`  ... those three all do the same thing on older and older browsers

Comment: It looks like the result is already split if you can call it that way. Try `addEnds(‘2,3,5,8,0’)`

Comment: Thank you Mark_M and Jaromanda X !!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function shared is working absolutely fine. Just ensure that the argument that you are passing is a string.

Please follow the below fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6pennzrb/

```
function addEnds(list) {
    var array = new Array();
    array = list.split(',');
    console.log(array);
}
addEnds("1,2,3,4,5")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
const stringToArray = ([...list], delimeter = ',') => list.filter(el => el != delimeter)
const result = stringToArray('1,2,3,4,5')
console.log(result)
```